# Sharing an immutable reference to a Send resource in Rust

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I am trying to get some async Rust going, to allow concurrent access to a database. I understand futures need to have 'Send' implemented for all the variables that can be held whilst it is awaited, but I am specifically importing Send for the Database itself, as well as declaring it on the input type.

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait Database: Send {
    async fn get_something(&self) -> Option<Vec<f32>>;
}

async fn calculate_something(&mut self, db: Arc<(dyn Database + Send)>, var: i16) -> Option<f32> {
    let something = db.get_something(var).await;
    // Do stuff with the something.

    Some()
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
^ future created by async block is not `Send`
help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn database::Database + Send`
note: captured value is not `Send`
  --> src/alarms/something_calculator.rs:31:47
   |
31 |     async fn calculate_something(&mut self, db: Arc<(dyn Database + Send)>,     var: i16) -> Option<f32> {
   |                                               ^^ has type `Arc<dyn database::Database + Send>` which is not `Send`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Future<Output = Option<f32>> + Send`
```

I am new to rust so I'm sure I am doing something silly, but I can't wrap my head around it not implementing Send when it is defined as a Send in its type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async function requires all captured values to be `Send` such that itself is `Send`. For the `Arc` type to be `Send` its type argument must be [`Sync + Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-Send). You can write `db: Arc<(dyn Database + Send + Sync)>` to make the async Future send.

It mentions this in the error message:

```
help: the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `dyn database::Database + Send
```

This change might have further consequences for your code if the `db` argument is not already `Sync`, but you are not providing enough context to determine that.

Comment: Thank you. The database is not currently Sync, because it has an internal connection pool, Arc<Mutex<Pool>>. Each thread that uses it has to call a method on the pool to create a client, which I think means it can't become Sync? How is this usually done in Rust?

Comment: A `Mutex` is `Sync` if the type is `Send`. So if you have a send type you need to make `Sync` you can wrap it in a `Mutex`. Your `Arc<Mutex<Pool>>` will be `Send + Sync` if `Pool` is `Send`.